# iPhone Dev - Implementing checkmarks in a tableview that is in edit mode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I know how to use checkmarks in a tableview when it is not in edit mode. But once in edit mode, it seems that it won't allow me to add checkmarks. Any ideas how to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Detail accessories are pushed offscreen during editing. This is native behavior and unless you have a peculiar use case it's perfectly fine. If you are editing to sort by checked vs. unchecked, do that automatically. If you really need to, poke around in the methods of your table's delegate. [Protocol reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can use the built in UIImageView that is on the cell so that when you are editing, if your table allows the editing of multiple rows, when the user taps the cell, the UIImageView is filled with the image of a check mark, but when the table is not in edit mode then the UIImageView is empty.

You can use the allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing property of UITableView to decide whether cells are selectable in editing mode.

Then calling indexPathsForSelectedRows will give you the indexPath of the rows the user has selected, and then perhaps you can have some logic to edit the cell's UIImageView property.

A bit hackey, but I hope this helps!